# Testing a MVC5 Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new to MVC and I am trying to test my application. When I created the application I did not select add test project. I have added a unit test project and am trying to test a controller however when I enter the controller name the type or namespace cannot be found and asks if I am missing a assembly reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you added a reference to your web project?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes ive added `using ProjectName;` however that is underlined and asking if i am missing an assemble reference

Comment: A `using` statement is not adding the reference! Right click on the 'References' folder in your test project and 'Add Reference'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it, step by step.

In my solution, I have `MyEmailer.UI` is a `MVC` project, then I add a test project named `MyEmailer.Test`. Now, to call `HomeContrller` from `MyEmailer.UI` in `MyEmailer.Test`, we do it like this:

[image: First step]
Right click `References` in your test project (`MyEmailer.Test`), choose `Add Reference`.

[image: Second step]
On the left side, choose `Solution --> Project`. On the right side, check your `MVC` project (`MyEmailer.UI`).

[image: Third step]
Notice on the `References`, add a library called `System.Web.Mvc`. Then, in your `UnitTest.cs`, add the `using`.

Now, you can call your controllers from your test project.